# Opening element(url) in new tabs in Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Objective:**
Need to open a webpage, find urls by class and then open each url in a new tab in chrome

**What I tried:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\xxx\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://xxxxxxxx.com")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("post-comments")
for e in elements:
    e.click()
driver.quit()
```

**current output:**

It's just opening the first url in the same parent window then stop there.. focus is not going to base url so it is not able to open second and other urls in new tab.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Update1: when I search for relative xpath, I came to know that I need to use regexp so that I can find all links containing "respond" in it.
For that I tried to use

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='respond']]")
```

but it errored there is no find_element.

**Update 2:**
After some trials, I am able to achieve to the most output that I require with below code. But below code is working on first page only, when below code completes for first page, then there will be 'NextPage' button , I need to click on that to open that page, that will become new main page and I need to run the below piece of code again on that page. How to tell below piece of code once elements on this page done, click on 'NextPage' button and run below logic for that page. Please suggest

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\xxx\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://xxxxxxxx.com")
current_windows_handle = driver.current_window_handle
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('h2.post-title.entry-title>a')
for ele in (elements):
    url = [ele.get_attribute("href")]
    for x in url:
          time.sleep(2)
          driver.execute_script("window.open('');") 
          handles = driver.window_handles
          driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
          driver.get(x)
          driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='mb-text'][contains(.,'Posts')]").click()
          time.sleep(2)
          driver.close()
          driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
          time.sleep(5)
          actualurl = driver.current_url
          with open(r'c:\test\new.txt', 'a') as text_file:
              text_file.write(actualurl + '\n')
          driver.close()
          time.sleep(5)
          driver.switch_to.window(current_windows_handle)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is valid, cause

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='respond']]")
```

this is syntax error, but since it is wrapped inside `""`, compiler won't show it.

try this instead :

```
elements =  driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='respond']")
```

and then print the length like this :-

```
print(len(elements))
```

I am assuming that it will have some elements in it. and you can iterate it as well. Pleas see below, it should help you figure out how to simulate those actions.

```
current_windows_handle = driver.current_window_handle
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='respond']")
for ele in elements:
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');") # open a new tab.
    handles = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
    driver.get(ele.get_attribute('href'))
    time.sleep(2)
    # Now it would have loaded a new url in new tab.
    # do whatever you wanna do.
    # Now close the new tab
    driver.close()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.window(current_windows_handle)
```

**updated 1 :**

```
current_windows_handle = driver.current_window_handle
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='respond']")
j = 0 
for ele in range(len(elements)):
    time.sleep(2)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='respond']")
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');") # open a new tab.
    handles = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
    driver.get(elements[j].get_attribute('href'))
    time.sleep(2)
    j = j + 1
    # Now it would have loaded a new url in new tab.
    # do whatever you wanna do.
    # Now close the new tab
    driver.close()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.window(current_windows_handle)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for explanation. now with that its printing correct length, but next part of code which suggested, when I included, its opening a new tab and nothing there.. giving below error  `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: @asp :  at which line ?

Comment: driver.get(ele.get_attribute('href')) this line

Comment: Yeah will give a try, for your reference, when I use chrome extension True path and hover this object i get this kind of value` //a[@href='https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/#respond']`   so this the reason why i am trying to search by respond as key word

Comment: See we are using css above `a[href*='respond']`, `//` is for xpath. you can have a equivalence xpath as `//a[contains(@href,'respond')]`

Comment: I have tried your updated one same issue again. when I use chrome extension True path and hover this object i get this kind of value` //a[@href='xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/#respond']`  is this correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236753/discussion-between-asp-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: I have updated main post with Update2. I need little more help. After some trials, I am able to achieve to the most output that I require code in Update2 in main post . But code is working on first page only, when below code completes for first page, then there will be 'NextPage' button , I need to click on that to open that page, that will become new main page and I need to run the below piece of code again on that page. How to tell below piece of code once elements on this page done, click on 'NextPage' button and run below logic for that page. Please suggest

Comment: See the first time when you are doing `driver.close()
          driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`, then index has to be `[0]` not 1.